# Mulitpart forms and nested objects Insomnia REST client

Tags: nested-object, insomnia

So I've decided to switch to Insomnia from Postman, as for some reason my Postman app keeps hanging. Everything is going well but I'm having trouble using multipart forms with Insomnia. How would I access this in Insomnia? In Postman I just need to put profile{location} as the field and it works, but Insomnia gives me an error of `can't read property '0' of undefined`

The object is structured as follows

```
{
  "id": "5e76dd60d49dfd6827688908",
  "username": "TLCFan",
  "email": "tlc@fan.com",
  "profile": {
    "avatar": {
      "url": "/static/img/defaultAvatar.png"
    },
    "header": {
      "url": "/static/img/defaultBG.png"
    },
    "forHire": false,
    "location": "Bimingham",
    "bio": "Design is my life, but this is my story"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try using square brackets